# How can I translate this game loop into Linux (C)

Tags: c, linux, vim, codeblocks, game-loop

So I'm totally beginner and I started to build a snake game in C. I have a field, a snake body and I did a game loop for it but it only works in Codeblocks, because in Linux there is no windows.h library and I cant really translate it. Here is my little function for game loop:

```
int ResetScreenPosition() {
HANDLE hOut;
COORD Position;
hOut = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
Position.X = 0;
Position.Y = 0;
SetConsoleCursorPosition(hOut,Position);
}
```

All I need is the cursor needs to go back to position(0,0) and from there the loops goes on. My code works in codeblocks, I want to write it in Linux, text editor : vim .

Comment: Look at the `ncurses` library.

Comment: Read [*Advanced Linux Programming*](http://www.makelinux.net/alp/) then [intro(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/intro.2.html). Learn about [libSFML](https://www.sfml-dev.org/) or [GTK](http://gtk.org)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way for set the cursor position to coordinate 0,0 is this:

```
void ResetScreenPosition(void){
  printf("\033[%d;%dH", 0, 0);
}
```